# Link (via url) to specific node in infovis (jit) treemap

Tags: javascript, jit, toolkit, treemap, infovis

Any infovis toolkit users out there? Would surely appreciate your help.

I'm wondering if there's a way to link to a specific node via a standard href or some other method.

Specifically, I'd like to retain the current node that the user is viewing while switching to a different view (link to a different set of data for the same entities).

I've appended the current node to an HTML element (a div on the same page, easy enough) but can't find anything in the documentation about targeting a specific node via link.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure whatyou mean but for me it was easy enough to have links on nodes by using the label on the node.

E.g if I wanted to link to a specific page when I click on one node I would say

```
label.innerHTML = '<a href="somepage.html">Click Me </a>';
```

Hope this helps !!

--EDIT--

Sorry I think I might understand you now, if you specifically want to target one particular node when you click a link (i.e. that when the link is clicked a selected node will be clicked)

Could you try something like having some javascript running that when the link is clicked so that it will find the requested node in the graph and then call

```
tm.enter(node);
```

Where tm is the tree map you are using

Apologies if this does not answer your question ,I am not entirely sure what your problem is.